# On Linux, Drag and drop from a Windows shared directory does not work

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, samba

I have tested this on a few Linux distributions such as Ubuntu, Linux Mint or Fedora, but the result was always the same. Double clicking a media file from a Windows shared directory (Samba) opens the file with the default player (say, VLC), but drag-and-dropping the same file from the file browser program (Nemo?) to the player (VLC) does not work.

Is there any way to make drag-and-drop from a Windows shared directory work, for any application, like how it works on Windows? When double-clicked, the system seems to map that file to a local directory automatically and passes that address to the application. If double-clicking works, I do not know why drag-and-drop cannot work by the same way.